# VBA Code to extract Document ID and Description from header in multiple MS Word documents and automatic populated in a separate word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

Extract Document ID and description from header in multiple MS Word documents and should be automatically populated in a separate word document which has columns document type, Document ID, location of evidence, revision and description:

```
Multiple MS Word documents Folder location:
C:\Users\MURALV05\Desktop\Value Creation\Value Creation\1. SUPPLIER EVALUATION & AGREEMENTS
C:\Users\MURALV05\Desktop\Value Creation\Value Creation\2. PLANNING
C:\Users\MURALV05\Desktop\Value Creation\Value Creation\3. DESIGN INPUT
C:\Users\MURALV05\Desktop\Value Creation\Value Creation\4. DESIGN OUTPUT
C:\Users\MURALV05\Desktop\Value Creation\Value Creation\5. DESIGN VERIFICATION
C:\Users\MURALV05\Desktop\Value Creation\Value Creation\8. RISK MANAGEMENT
C:\Users\MURALV05\Desktop\Value Creation\Value Creation\10. DESIGN CHANGE HISTORY LOG
```

```
Sub ExtractTablesFromMultiDocs()
  Dim objTable As Table
  Dim objDoc As Document, objNewDoc As Document
  Dim objRange As Range
  Dim strFile As String, strFolder As String

  '  Initialization
  strFolder = InputBox("C:\Users\MURALV05\Desktop\Value Creation\Value Creation: ")
  strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\" & "*.docx", vbNormal)

  Set objNewDoc = Documents.Add

  '  Process each file in the folder.
  While strFile <> ""
    Set objDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile)
    Set objDoc = ActiveDocument

    For Each objTable In objDoc.Tables
      objTable.Range.Select
      Selection.Copy

      Set objRange = objNewDoc.Range
      objRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
      objRange.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteRTF
      objRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
      objRange.Text = vbCr
    Next objTable

    objDoc.Save
    objDoc.Close
    strFile = Dir()
  Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/45024-extract-document-id-description-header-multiple-word.html. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184.

Comment: where to post the code?

Comment: Click the edit link below your original post, then add the code.

Comment: i have added the code. Please help...